# OpenSSL RSA signing with SHA256 digest

Tags: ruby, shell, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent shell script of a small ruby script I have. This is the ruby script:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

k = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("key.pem"))
res = File.read("res.tmp")
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
signature = k.sign(digest,res)
File.write("foo1.txt",Base64.strict_encode64(signature))
```

That's it. It takes some data, gets the SHA256 hash of it, and then signs that with a private key I have. I think that the equivalent command on the terminal should be:

```
openssl sha -sha256 -sign key.pem < res.tmp | base64 -w 0 > foo2.txt
```

But these do not produce the same output. Could anyone enlighten me as to why?

-- EDIT --

I'm adding some more information so that people can try to reproduce this on their computers if so desired. The contents of `res.tmp` are:

```
This is some sample text. 
This is some sample text. 
This is some sample text. 
This is some more sample text. 
This is some more sample text. 
This is some more sample text.
```

The private key (which is **not** a private key that is actually used for any production system, just clarifying that) is:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now, anyone should be able to run the commands I gave above and get the same results. The shell script produces this as its output:

```
l4BxJyo/GQ0vUF5YR/vO7NtX5Sn/9bGfNHiVGS+W1CMfrwVlCtT0afHERXowx5T8mOiZ90VCJioHMj9Z6ssmfF1SpUbpoo1HYwNBCAfEcIjPLBj4N4KDLpy4gbMZtHEo2B8DZitYLwYDyvkCEudrMiU9b39DqOL+p3pwjJxT5iE=
```

With no trailing newline of course. The ruby script produces:

```
l4BxJyo/GQ0vUF5YR/vO7NtX5Sn/9bGfNHiVGS+W1CMfrwVlCtT0afHERXowx5T8mOiZ90VCJioHMj9Z6ssmfF1SpUbpoo1HYwNBCAfEcIjPLBj4N4KDLpy4gbMZtHEo2B8DZitYLwYDyvkCEudrMiU9b39DqOL+p3pwjJxT5iE=
```

Also without a trailing newline. I've only base 64 encoded the results to make them presentable to humans. That part is not the problem. The real issue is that my invocations of openssl in the ruby script and the shell script are doing different things. In the comments people keep asking about intermediate results. Just to be clear, the only thing that can be considered an "intermediate result" in the raw binary result before the base64 encoding (and it would be both unhelpful and impossible for me to post that here). The openssl command I'm running is just one opaque command (in both scripts), so I don't have access to the SHA256 hash in either case. I suppose that it would be generated with this command:

```
sha256sum res.tmp
```

Which gives this at the command line:

```
688a84cb84ce3b203460a2775248a31d4c3e9590a41ba27134dc342c328b8f9c  res.tmp
```

But I cannot be certain that the hash above is actually any intermediate result of either of the two scripts. Let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same result from the ruby script every time? Do you get the same intermediate result from the ruby script and the openssl command? What version of openssl are you using?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes. Both scripts are completely deterministic. They both give the same results every time they are run. The "intermediate result" (if by that you mean the raw binary data before it has been base64 encoded) is also the same every time. I don't know what version of openssl is on the computer is was running these commands on, but it should just be the one in the ubuntu quantum quetzal repo.

Comment: Is the intermediate step identical between the two scripts? (That is which step is causing the different output.)

Comment: Are they both definitely producing a sha256 hash (ie does the length look right? Should be about 43-44 bytes)

Comment: Both Ruby and OpenSSL command produce exactly the same results on my machine ... though I'm not getting the same results as you, because the sha256 sum is different for res.tmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow, I ended up mistaken, and it appears that these two scripts are indeed producing the same output. Sorry.

Comment: Given the circumstances I don't think the question is very useful anymore, then ;-)

Comment: That is true. If someone would like to close or remove it, I would be fine with that.